# Change timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I lived in philippines and when I'm inserting date in my database, It's inserting less 13 hours in my database. For example, our datetime here is 02-11-2016 21-04-00, when I insert, it's inserting 02-11-2016 08-04-00

I already used this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

But no luck. I already put the website in my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done by

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

Make sure you are uploading the correct files.

If it doesn't work; try making a page for error handling, then echo a variable that will set the time for this timezone, if it works. Use that variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you have pasted php function which will just set `time_zone` for php not for `my_sql`. mysql has global `time_zone` variable which can be set. You should use `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;` or `SET time_zone = timezone;`.

If you dont have direct control of your DB server in that case you can pass the 2nd statement i.e `set time_zone=...;` as 1st statement.

Alternatively you can also use the `convert_tz` function to convert an already stored value.

Comment: Yes, for php only. Where do I set the GLOBAL time_zone?

Comment: If you have direct access to mysql configuration files this can be set in my.cnf or my.ini depending on platform. if not before invoking actual query you can invoke set time_zone=  e.g 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"));
or mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'Europe/London")

Comment: I have connection.php and I put the mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+13:00') because all my page have connection.php but it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, I don't have direct access. I'm just borrowing my instructor's domain.

Comment: change in time_zone is for all new insertion or updation. Existing stored value will not change. now() will give different value. all timestamp function uses this.
 If you can brief exact situation of yours i will try to simulate and find out
For your old data you can try this : update mytable set dtime=convert_tz(dtime,"+00:00","+13:00") assuming dtime is field and mytable is table

Comment: SET time_zone = '+02:00';
INSERT INTO `tblannouncement`(`announcementid`, `title`, `content`, `date`, `userid`, `image`) VALUES (null, "asd", "asd", "2016-01-01 01:01:01", 1, "asd.asd"); I did that but its inserting the exact datetime i put in my values

Comment: This is correct only. whatever value you will insert hard coded will not be influenced by mysql time_zone. As i mentioned all functions which is returning date time will see the effect of time_zone. How mysql can take decision that weather you are inserting the value with timezone or without. But if you want automatic conversion you can write before_insert trigger on row which will just do that change in that field before saving

Answer (score 1):

The timezone you set is used for PHP as Bimal said, you need to check the server time as well, because time is very sensitive part of the information you don't want to miss or play with.

I've been in that situation couple of weeks back, there are two ways to fix it:

- Set the server timezone to the correct timezone.
- If the time difference is always and EXACTLY 13 hours, use this approach:

  $new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+13 hours')).

I ended up using the second method as the first one was not an option for me.

Best of Luck.

Comment: I already thought of the second option, but It will take time because, there are so many php file that I have to edit. I'm meeting a deadline in our project.

Comment: You can use a quick fix, create a PHP file and make it update the timestamp to the correct value, then when submitting a new value, make sure to add 13 hours after you insert it to the database.